# Heatmap in Julia

Tags: julia, visualization, heatmap

I am trying to create a heat map. I have the following code. Is there a simple way to create a heatmap, s.t. lst1 is the x-axis, lst2 is the y-axis and lst ist the intensity in the graph?

```
lst1 = []
lst2 = []
lst3 = []
for i in range(0,3.5,step = 0.5)
    for j in range(0,4,step = 0.5)
        println(i,j)
        a = f(parameter,i,j)
        push!(lst1,i)
        push!(lst2,j)
        push!(lst3,a)
        print("($i , $j): $a %")
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat shorter way of doing this, utilizing broadcasts, might be:

```
lst1 = 0:0.5:3.5
lst2 = 0:0.5:4

lst3 = f.(Ref(parameter), lst1, lst2')
```

lst1 and lst2 are constructed using the colon operator but are equivalent to the range call you showed.

lst3 is constructed using the Julia broadcast operator.  Here, we wrap `parameter` in a `Ref` (think of it as a zero dimensional array or a pointer) to indicate that it should not be expanded during the broadcast.  We pass lst1 as is, and its form mimics a column vector.  We then pass the transpose of lst2 (obtained by the `'` operator) which makes it have the form of a row vector.

These two differing dimensions cause the broadcast to create a Matrix with the first axis being lst1 and the second axis being lst2.  For clarity you can examine the output of `tuple.(lst1, lst2')`, which will show you essentially the values passed into the function `f`.

In the end, lst3 will be a Matrix of elements of the type which `f` returns.

To actually plot this you should consider using the Plots.jl or Makie.jl packages.

Sorry I can't provide code examples right now, posting this on mobile.  Will reformat later.

Answer (score 0):

You may do it like this with [`Plots.jl`](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl)

```
using Plots

f = (x, y) -> x^2 + y^2

x = range(-1, 1; length=10)
y = range(-2, 2; length=40)
z = fill(NaN, size(y, 1), size(x, 1))

for i in eachindex(x), j in eachindex(y)
    z[j, i] = f(x[i], y[j])
end
heatmap(x, y, z)
```

[image]

`Plots.heatmap` waits for rectangular matrix of z-values, which I preallocated before the cycle. In this matrix, x-direction corresponds to the columns and y-direction to the rows.

```
z as matrix      z when plotted

z11 z12 z13      z31 z32 z33
z21 z22 z23      z21 z22 z23
z31 z32 z33      z11 z12 z13
```

Take a look at

```
z = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]
heatmap(z)  # heatmap(1:size(z, 2), 1:size(z, 1), z)
```

[image]

Things to improve

- replace `fill` with uninitialised matrix constructor
- construct x-y pairs, e.g. by `Iterators.product` instead of nested loops
- use broadcasting